# Stata error when using new commands

Tags: command, stata

I need some help with Stata. I'm not sure if this is the right forum, but hopefully somebody can help me.

The problem occur, when I want to use new commands in stata. I will explain it with an example: command outreg. I assume the problem is the version.

Stata Details:

- Version 10.1
- Unlimited-user Stata for Windows (network) perpetual license (decompressed in C:\Program Files (x86)\Stata)

I downloaded the command `ssc install outreg`

I tried the new command with the example given here:
http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/outreg.htm

After execution, the following error occur, after `outreg using test.doc, nolabel replace`

```
          MakeSmat():  3499  _CColJoin() not found
         CalcStats():     -  function returned error
             <istmt>:     -  function returned error
```

Stata.com also provide a solution for the problem:
http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-07/msg01018.html but a restart of stata doesn't work for my problem.

The necessary library (**l_cfrmt** described in the stata.com link) is also available:

```
. mata : mata query
    Mata settings
        set matastrict      off
        set matalnum        off
        set mataoptimize    on
        set matafavor       space      may be space or speed
        set matacache       400        kilobytes
        set matalibs        lmatabase;lmataado;lmataopt;l_cfrmt
        set matamofirst     off
```

But when I search for the usage of the library l_cfrmt (which is necessary for outreg) there occur the following error-message:

```
. mata : mata desc using l_cfrmt
c:\ado\plus\l\l_cfrmt.mlib from a more recent version of Stata
```

It looks, if the version, which I loaded via ssc is not compatible with the Version 10.1 of Stata.

Does somebody have any idea how to solve this problem? I search for a few hours now, but I did't find any possible solution.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: Looks like you may have to contact the authors of the package and ask if they're willing to provide the Mata source code for that compiled library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the code you found on the ucla website for -outreg- is not correct -- John Gallup has since made many changes to the latest version of -outreg-, one of which affects your example.  (ignoring your mata issue for a moment) This code should be modified to this in order to make it run:

```
**install latest outreg
ssc install outreg, replace

use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/notes/hsb1, clear
regress read write
 outreg using test.doc, novarlabel replace
```

the code above works on my machine with an updated version of Stata 12 MP and updated -outreg- version 4.12.

Regarding the mata error:  It might be the case that the newest -outreg- just might not work with Stata 10.1 - but I wouldn't give up yet.  First, make sure your Stata is fully updated (-update query- and -update all-).
Second, follow the advice of the author of -outreg- in this Statalist thread:

http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-07/msg01014.html

Finally, if you do have a missing mata component/library, as that thread hints at, and cannot follow this advice to correct it,  then consider re-installing Stata and/or contacting Stata tech support.